# json gson получение данных

Tags: android, json, retrofit

Не могу получить данные от сервера.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
private void getInfo(){

        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(Constants.BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();

        RequestInterface requestInterface = retrofit.create(RequestInterface.class);


        ServerRequest request = new ServerRequest();
        request.setOperation(Constants.GET_INFO);


        Call<ServerResponse> response = requestInterface.operation(request);

        response.enqueue(new Callback<ServerResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<ServerResponse> call, retrofit2.Response<ServerResponse> response) {

                ServerResponse resp = response.body();
                Snackbar.make(getView(), resp.getMessage(), Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                if(resp.getResult().equals(Constants.SUCCESS)){
 //                   Log.d(Constants.TAG,resp.getMessage());
//                    String[] arr = resp.getInfo();
                    Log.d(Constants.TAG,"ok!!!");
//                    for (int i =0 ;i<arr.length;i++)
//                    {
//                        Log.d("Array Value",arr[i]);
//                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<ServerResponse> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.d(Constants.TAG,"failed!!!!!");
                Snackbar.make(getView(), t.getLocalizedMessage(), Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
        });
    }
```

ServerResponse

```
package com.example.user.salon;


import java.util.Map;

public class ServerResponse {

    private String result;
    private String message;
    private User user;
    //
    private String info;
    private Map masters;

    public String getResult() {
        return result;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public User getUser() {
        return user;
    }


//
    public Map getMasters(){
        return masters;
    }

    public String getInfo(){
        return info;
    }
}
```

в снэкбар выдает expected a string but was begin_object. Как вывести все данные в Log

Comment: Покажите класс ServerResponse

Comment: точно. добавил выше...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В ответе от сервера info - объект. А вы его пытаетесь распарсить как строку:

```
private String info;
```

Стоит добавить класс Info.

```
public class Info {
   private String address;
   private String name;
}
```

Затем, использовать его в ***ServerResponse***

```
public class ServerResponse {
    private String result;
    private String message;
    private Info info;
    ....
    ....
    ....
}
```

Comment: ну да.  он на это и ругается. А как правильно парсить?

Comment: @alexeySmirnov, глянь, я дополнил ответ

Comment: да помогло. А как мне теперь полученный info в Log вывести. Я просто совсем новичок еще )

Comment: 1) в ServerResponse добавить публичный метод Info getInfo(); 
2) Для Info добавить метод переводящий его в строку для вывода. Например String toDisplayableString() {return "addrres = " + address;}

3) В том месте где хотите вывести. Log.e("TAG", serverResponse.getInfo.toDisplayableString());